# Variable not getting set from within function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-js

I come from a Python background and have very little JavaScript experience, so I'm a little bit out of my element here.

I'm trying to do something seemingly simple, get an AWS account ID and store it in a variable.  I'm referencing the code from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563270/finding-my-aws-account-id-using-javascript) but I've modified it a bit.

```
var account =  sts.getCallerIdentity({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error ", err)
    } else {
        account = data.Account.toString();
        console.log(account);
        return account

    }
});
//console.log(account);
```

If I leave the console.log statement commented out, I see the AWS account ID being printed to the console, which is what I'm expecting.  However, if I uncomment the line, I get a very big object (which I assume is actually the *data* variable) that is being printed to the console.

I just want the *account* variable to be equal to the account ID.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: well, I'd change `var account` to `let account` (or `const`) and in `else` I'd do only `return data.Account.toString();`, but then you need to return something from the `if` also, so for ex. `return null` there

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either.  I'm getting the same result as I did in the original question.

Comment: Well, we don't know what `sts.getCallerIdentity` really does

Answer (score 1):

The function is async so you cant really assign the value. The value gets resolved in the callback at some time in the future. By this point the `console.log` has already executed.

You can do 2 things, add your logic that requires `account` in the callback or use promises.

```
sts.getCallerIdentity({}).promise().then((data) => console.log(data));
sts.getCallerIdentity({}, (err, data) => {...stuff});
```

Remember these values are resolved sometime in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The account variable won't get set with the data you need until the callback is run. Perhaps try something like this?

```js
var account = sts.getCallerIdentity({}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error ", err)
    } else {
        account = data.Account.toString();
        doOtherStuff();
    }
});

function doOtherStuff() {
  console.log(account);
}
```